# How do I filter a view (of feeds imported data) based upon the user that started the import?

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting, entities

What I'm really trying to achieve here is to get data from a third party hotel availability source (XML) and present that freshly received filtered list to the site visitor.

Here's the approach I've taken so far:

1. **Entityforms** collects the requirements from the customer (city, arrival date, duration of stay) which then redirects a local page to run the import with variables passed in the URL `mysite.example/searching?city=' . $city . '&sDate=' . $arrive . '&nights=' . $nights . ''`
2. mysite.example.local/searching then runs explodes those variables and passes them to the **Feeds** import 
   `$URL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $link_array = explode('/',$URL);
   $query = parse_url($URL, PHP_URL_QUERY);
   parse_str($query, $params);
   $kword = $params['city'];
   $arrive = $params['arrive'];
   $nights = $params['nights'];
   // Define the id (machine name) of the importer you want to use.
   $importer_id = 'availability';
   // Load the Feeds Source object.
   $feeds_source = feeds_source($importer_id);
   // Override configurations...
   $feeds_config = $feeds_source->getConfigFor($feeds_source->importer->fetcher);
   $feeds_config['source'] = 'http://supplier.example.com?city=' . $city . '&date=' . $arrive . '&nights=' . $nights . '';
   $feeds_source->setConfigFor($feeds_source->importer->fetcher, $feeds_config);
   $feeds_source->save();
   // Execute the import.
   $feeds_source->Import();`
3. Redirect to **Views** to present the data to the visitor. with `header( "Location: http://mysite.example.com/hotels/" . $city . "/" . $arrive . "/" . $nights . "" );`

I'm sure there is a better way to handle this, (but that's a subjective question, so I'm not asking it)

So, my problem is that I have no way to filter against the initial query. One way would be to add the Entityforms submission ID to the Feeds import, but I can't find how to do this.

My question is, can I pass a field value (the Entityform submission id would be ideal) to Feeds that will be saved in the node so that I can then filter my view on it?

For instance could I add a variable into `$feeds_config['source'] = $entityforms_submission_id` and that variable into the earlier redirect? (I can do the variable in the redirect bit!)